# How to set multi marks with custom infowindow at Google maps api for ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, infowindow

I have a question. I am set google maps API for ios native code.

I am use Google Maps API version 1.4.3.

I was custom marker infoWindow success in one mark.

But I can't set different infoWindow content about multi marks.

Have anyone can instruct me , how to pass different title and snippet to markerInfoWindow method? or How to know mark when I click?

I attack my code with one mark and custom markerInfoWindow part.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:25.03760471     longitude:121.5412 zoom:14];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,     _mapBackgroundView.frame.size.width,_mapBackgroundView.frame.size.height) camera:camera];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
    mapView.delegate = self;

    [self.mapBackgroundView addSubview:mapView];

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.03760471, 121.5412);
    marker.map = mapView;

    GMSMarker *marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.03760461, 121.5432);
    marker2.map = mapView;
}

-(UIView *) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    CustomInfoWindow *infoWindow = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow"   owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    infoWindow.titleLb.text = @"1th marks";
    infoWindow.snippetLb.text= @"1th marks snippet~";
    return infoWindow;
}
```

thank you very much~

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways... generally you need to write a custom class and set some unique id there to identify the marker correctly later in the delegated method... but here's an wasy way...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:25.03760471     longitude:121.5412 zoom:14];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,     _mapBackgroundView.frame.size.width,_mapBackgroundView.frame.size.height) camera:camera];
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
        mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
        mapView.delegate = self;

        [self.mapBackgroundView addSubview:mapView];

        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.03760471, 121.5412);
        marker.map = mapView;
        marker.title= @"1st marker"; // set some title here

        GMSMarker *marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.03760461, 121.5432);
        marker2.title= @"2nd marker";
        marker2.map = mapView;
}


-(UIView *) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
{

    CustomInfoWindow *infoWindow = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow"   owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    infoWindow.titleLb.text = marker.title;  // change the text according to the marker displayed here
    infoWindow.snippetLb.text= @"1th marks snippet~";


    return infoWindow;
}
```